# Get element sibling value in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this method inside a React component (which I later pass to the render() method):

```
renderNutrientInputs: function (num) {
    var inputs = [];
    for (var i =0; i < num; i++) {
        inputs.push(<div key={i}>
            <label>Nutrient name: </label><input type="text"/>
            <label>Nutrient value: </label><input type="text" />
        </div>);
    }

    return inputs;
}
```

I'm trying on each change of the "Nutrient value" textbox, to also grab the current value of the "Nutrient name" textbox. I first though of assigning "ref" to both of them, but I figured there might be multiple pairs of them on the page (and the only way to identify them would be by key). I also tried something like this:

```
<label>Nutrient name: </label><input type="text" ref="nutName"/>
<label>Nutrient value: </label><input type="text" onChange={this.handleNutrientValueChange.bind(null, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nutName))}/>
```

but got a warning from React:

> Warning: AddForm is accessing getDOMNode or findDOMNode inside its
>   render(). render() should be a pure function of props and state. It
>   should never access something that requires stale data from the
>   previous render

Is there some way to attach onChange event listener to Nutrient value text box and access the current value of "Nutrient name" textbox in the event listener function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to access DOM elements directly. There is no need to do so... Work with your data, forget about DOM!

What you want is to "listen to changes to n-th nutritient. I want to know it's name and it's value". You will need to store that data somewhere, let's say in `state` in this example.

Implement `getInitialState` method. Let's begin with empty array, let user to add nutritients.

```
getInitialState() {
    return { nutritients: [] };
},
```

In `render` method, let user add nutrition by click on "+", let's say

```
addNutritient() {
    const nutritients = this.state.nutritients.concat();
    nutritients.push({ name: "", value: undefined });
    this.setState({ nutritients });
},

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={this.addNutritient}>+</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Okay, let's focus on rendering and updating nutritients:

```
addNutritient() {
    const nutritients = this.state.nutritients.concat();
    nutritients.push({ name: "", value: undefined });
    this.setState({ nutritients });
},

renderNutritients() {
    const linkNutritient = (idx, prop) => {
        return {
            value: this.state.nutritients[idx][prop],
            requestChange: (value) {
                const nutritients = this.state.nutritients.concat();
                nutritients[idx][prop] = value;
                this.setState({ nutritients });
            },
        }
    };

    const nutritients = [];
    return (
        this.state.nutritients.map((props, idx) => (
            <div>
                <input valueLink={linkNutritient(idx, "name")} />
                <input valueLink={linkNutritient(idx, "value")} />
            </div>
        ))
    )
},

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { this.renderNutritients() }
            <div onClick={this.addNutritient}>+</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Coding by hand, sorry for syntax error or typings.

**Edit:**
Take a look at this working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lfrk2932/
Play with it, it will help you to understand what's going on.
Also, take a look at React docs, especialy "valueLink" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#reactlink-without-linkedstatemixin

Comment: I'm having a very hard time grasping your code, still don't know ES6 syntax, I'm writing in ES5.

Comment: valueLink uses a two-way binding polyfill, also not familiar with that concept :/

Comment: Take a look at updated reply. I added working Fiddle, plus added link to docs which will help you understand two way binding. Basically it replaces `value` and `onChange` props with one prop, which contains input's value and function which is invoked to change it's value.

Comment: Also, you can paste source from Fiddle to https://babeljs.io/repl/ and see ES5 codebase

Comment: I ended up with using the longer version instead of the two-way binding hack. But there was a bigger lesson here...work with your data and forget about your DOM. Thus I've changed my app to basically sync with the data as soon as the user does something I care about (types something inside a field etc.) This was a huge lesson for me...either sync asap or suffer the consequences. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you at least a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use 2 way binding with React which is kind of a flux anti-pattern. Just add a onChange listener to your input element and setState.

Your state will be something like this: 
{0: {nutrientName: xyz, nutrientValue: 123},
1: {nutrientName: abc, nutrientValue: 456}}

So when you change the nutrientvalue 456 to say 654, you can say its corresponding name is abc and vice versa.

The whole thing about React is about handling the data not the DOM :)